# how to append - automatically in date format in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, client-side, keyup

I have a text box i need to append "-" in date format

Like I type DD-MM-YYYY in text box

when users enter Date-(This should automatically come) than month (- this should automatically come ) and than later year

so when i enter something in text box like this

29-06-1992

How to do it in JavaScript or Jquery

Comment: Greeting Basant12 -- welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review [ask] to get some useful instructions on writing questions well suited for the StackOverflow community.

Comment: Can you  please write code in here is stackoverflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19709725/4946681

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#your_textbox_id',function(){
if($('#your_textbox_id').val().length == 2){
$('#your_textbox_id').val( $('#your_textbox_id').val().substring(0,2) +'-')
}
else if($('#your_textbox_id').val().length == 5){
$('#your_textbox_id').val( $('#your_textbox_id').val().substring(0,5) +'-')
}
})
```